# Storing different parameterized types in the same generic arraylist in Java

Tags: java, generics, parameterized-types

I like to create a class representation of database tables in java.
A column is designed as a generic class so that it can handle all different datatypes table columns can possible have.

```
public class TableColumn<T> {
    ...
}
```

A table has 0 ... n TableColumns, so my table class does look like that:

```
public class Table {
    protected ArrayList<TableColumn<T>> columns =
                new ArrayList<TableColumn<T>>();
    ...
}
```

The idea is to add columns in the following way.

```
Table t = new Table();
t.addColumn(String.class);
t.addColumn(Integer.class);
t.addColumn(Date.class);
t.addColumn(String.class);
```

And then i can manipulate data in the following way:

```
String a = t.Cols(2).Row(3);
t.Col(2).Row(3) = "b";
```

But i am loosing type safty with my current way of achiving that ... My problem is how to implement columns because of the different data types columns potential can get.

Does someone has a clue?

Comment: So you want `col(2)` to be of a different type than `col(3)`? That's not possible. Simply because the type checks happen at compile time, and the parameter *values* have no effect on those.

Comment: Is there any other practicable way of doing this? Another concept another structure?

Comment: You could *fake* this by having a `<T> T get()` method that just casts to `T`. That would allow `String x = foo.get()` and `Integer x = foo.get()` to compile. But that's also the drawback: you lose all compile-time type checks. It will simply crash-and-burn at runtime when you're using it wrong.

Comment: That's too bad, i absolutely want to keep type safety.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a limited amount of Type combinations you could use interfaces to be those combinations. This would allow you to be able to store the column in the same way, and you wouldn't need any special casting.

```
t.addColumn(MyInterface.class);
```

Another method, which would still wouldn't be quite as clean as what you want but is kind of unavoidable, is to use a new Class that allows you to take the burden of some of the casting and type checking away.

Example:

```
public static class MyWrapper{
    Class<?>[] validPossibleClasses;
    Object o;
    public MyWrapper(Class<?> ...classes){
        this.validPossibleClasses = classes;
    }
    public boolean validateClass(Class<?> clazz){
        for (Class<?> c : validPossibleClasses){
            if (!c.isAssignableFrom(clazz))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void set(Object o) throws Exception{
        if (!validateClass(o.getClass()))
            throw new Exception("Bad Cast");
        this.o = o;
    }
    public String getString(){
        return (String) o;
    }
    public Integer getInt(){
        return (Integer) o;
    }
    ...
    // more specific getters
}
```

The usage would be like this

```
String a = t.Cols(2).Row(3).getString();
t.Col(2).Row(3).set("b");
```

Comment: Can you explain that in more detail?

Comment: Wait, are you looking for an alternative way of storing the columns? or are having trouble using multiple types in one column?

Comment: Both. At first i want to use multiple types in one column without losing type safety. If that's not possible another approach would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a different object for each table you have?  Something like:

Class Players with fields:

```
String name;
int points;
int number;
```

Class Stadium with fields:

```
String location;
Date dateBuilt;
```

Class Team with fields:

```
String name;
ArrayList<Players> roster;
```

Then you could just hold all the values in a list or arraylist and have them separated by the database tables and not have to guess at which table you are in.  You'd have to hold onto more objects, but you would be able to know more what you're dealing with.

Comment: The problem is that i dont know how many columns my tables will have and i dont know of which type they will be neither...